# Плавная прокрутка страницы к якорям на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть некий скрипт плавной прокрутки страницы к якорям на jQuery, в примере работает отлично, на сайте wordpress выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined at HTMLDocument.

В чем может быть причина ошибки?
Можно ли сделать подобное на чистом js?

```js
(function() {
  var delay = false;

  jQuery(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

    var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    var a= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if(wd < 0) {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t >= 40) break;
      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t < -20) break;
      }
    }
    
    if(i >= 0 && i < a.length) {
      jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
      });
    }
  });
})();
console.clear();
```

```css
body {
  font:20pt verdana;
}

a {
  display:block;
  color:red;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="#A1">Tag #1.</a>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<hr>
<a id="#A2">Tag #2.</a>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
<hr>
<a id="#A3">Tag #3</a>
At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
<hr>
<a id="#A4">Tag #4.</a>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<hr>
<a id="#A5">Tag #5.</a>
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
```

Comment: Да какая разница, на чем делать. Можно и на чистом. Проблема не в WordPress и не в коде, скорее всего, а в том, как вы этот код подключаете на сайт.

Comment: Остальные jQuery скрипты работают нормально, прописаны там же, не работает только этот

Comment: Смотрите, в какой строке ошибка в dev tools, ставьте точку останова, проверяйте значения переменных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в плохом коде js. Читаем [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects):

For HTML AREA elements, SVG elements that do not render anything themselves, display:none elements, and generally any elements that are not directly rendered, an empty list is returned.

Для элементов HTML AREA, SVG элементов, которые не выводятся на экран, элементов с display:none, и в общем случае для элементов, которые не выводятся на экран, возвращается пустой список.

Вы пытаетесь обратиться к несуществующему элементу [0] в

```
var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
```

Здесь, в сниппете вопроса, у вас только "удобные" видимые ссылки. На реальном сайте ваш код натыкается на скрытые ссылки, и падает.

Замените строки с getClientRects() на

```
var t = a[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

и все будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало